# How to call from one authorized service to another service that requires authorization

Tags: servicestack

I have an Item Service:

```
[Authenticate]
public class ItemService : ServiceStack.Service {
    //implementation
}
```

Within the ItemService I am debugging this Get method that has received a valid Token and is able to successfully create session:

```
public GetItemResponse Get(GetItem request)
{
    var session = SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
    var authToks1 = session.GetAuthTokens();//empty
    var authToks2 = session.GetAuthTokens(_authServiceConnection);//null
    var authService = new JsonServiceClient(_authServiceConnection);

    //not authorized
    ConvertSessionToTokenResponse attempt1 = authService.Send(new ConvertSessionToToken());
    //not authorized
    ConvertSessionToTokenResponse attempt2 = authService.Send(new ConvertSessionToToken() { PreserveSession = true });

    var accountService = new JsonServiceClient(_accountServiceConnection)
    {
        BearerToken = "what to do",
        RefreshToken = "what to do"
    };

    return new GetItemResponse();
}
```

Obviously I am simply trying to call another service, `AccountService`:

```
[Authenticate]
public class AccountService : ServiceStack.Service {
    //implementation
}
```

How to include a JWT Refresh token or JWT Bearer token in a request from one authorized service to another service that has the ServiceStack `Authenticate` attribute.

Note I am using a custom Auth provider, I have a legacy database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this another ServiceStack Service with the same Host you should use the [Service Gateway](http://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) as internal requests are executed in process directly which avoid the request filter validation.

```
var response = Gateway.Send(new MyRequest());
```

If you're trying to call a remote ServiceStack Service you can get the JWT Token sent with the request with `IRequest.GetJwtToken()` extension method and forward it to the downstream Service requests:

```
var accountService = new JsonServiceClient(_accountServiceConnection)
{
    BearerToken = Request.GetJwtToken(),
};
```